# Exporting character with multiple equipable armor parts and animations from blender to unity (Blender 2.78)

Tags: animation, objects, export, import, unity

I have a problem with a character i created in blender: he has multiple equipable armor parts and multiple animations as well as additional bones for hands (for weapons). When i try to import it to Unity, however, it imports numerous empty animations for armor parts, that are not even in my animation list in blender as well as skipping the primary animations from it. The only option that worked differently, was when i exported as fbx with the option "all actions" disabled, but then it only imported 3 animations "Run" "Walk" and "Grip right" for some reason.

Also, in NLA editor, it shows me only 1 animation.
PS: I also have 3 instances of empty walk animations below with no users, that i can't get rid of even with shift+x and reloading.

[image]

[image]

There's also a problem with character just hovering frozen even with applied animations in Unity, but i think that's just Unity linking problem somewhere and unrelated to this issue.

PS: The warning message in unity is about activating translation DOF for improved animation retargeting which doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: When exporting to fbx, check the options on the right hand side. Most of the defaults are bad for unity. E.g. if you don't want to refine animation, you don't need non-deforming bones and especially not leaf bones. Using settings that make sense to you in regards to Unity might already solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it fixed (the animations importing part, at least). In FBX export options, had to change the version from FBX 7.4 binary to FBX 6.1 ASCII.

ARGGHH.